# Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error C2676 binary '>>': 'std::ifstream'

Tags: c++, ifstream

i am trying to define function in header file that takes 2 arguments, std::ifstream and char* .. function is going to check if char* type argument is in file then return true else it will return false. the compiler shows me the error message about ">>" operation with ifstream reference

P.S Note that, i am defining function in external my own header file

firstly i have passed parameter of fstream, then changed to ifstream but same error message

```
bool check_for_valid_name(std::ifstream &file, char* name) {
    char data[sizeof(name)];
    while (file.eof()) {
        file >> data;
        if (strcmp(data, name)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

it should work fine, just return false or true but the compiler shows error: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error C2676 binary '>>': 'std::ifstream'

Comment: `char data[sizeof(name)];` -- This does not do what you think it does, unless you want your array to be 4 or 8 in size.

Comment: [Cannot duplicate](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f6fc7d99af0c50d1)

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you get the error because your `while` condition is wrong. You have to read the file until end of the file. However, at the first attempt you get `false`. Also, here is my suggestions before reading data from file.

- Please be sure that file is already exist or not. `is_good()` would be used.
- Please use `const` if function parameters would not be changed in the function. For your case `bool check_for_valid_name(const std::ifstream &file, const char* name)`
- `sizeof(name)` will be calculated as a pointer, so it could be 4 or 8 byte depending on your architecture. If it is not your expected length, please use `strlen()` instead of this.
- If there is no restriction at all on your implementation, please use std::string instead of char arrays. It will help you to get rid of all C-style functions.